# Dataframe to insert number of rows according to cell content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A simple data-frame as below. I want to insert rows, according to the number of Projects the people had, for each people, and list their names one by one, like:

[image]

I can only work out:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Name' : ["John", "Kate", "Peter", "Linda"],
'Projects': ["YK;PO;IU","PK;JL;OL","OK","PL;IK"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    nr_of_rows = row['Projects'].count(';') + 1
    df.index = df.index + nr_of_rows # number of rows to be inserted
```

How can I proceed further?

Comment: use explode for pandas 0.25 + : `df.assign(Projects=df['Projects'].str.split(';')).explode('Projects')`

Comment: @anky_91, amazing! can you make it an answer so to close this question?

Comment: Glad it worked, however it is a duplicate and already closed :)